# Hide and show password on user click in ruby on rails

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-5, show-hide

I am a begineer in ruby on rails.I have tried many methods in ruby on rails to show and hide password on user click.But I was unable to create this If anyone can guide me how can I do this in ruby on rails.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using js. Bind the click event of eye icon and change type of your input field password to text. 
If you have eye icon with class name "eye_icon" and your password field with class name "pwd" then you can use below code

```
$(".eye_icon").on('click',function() {
    if ($(".pwd").attr('type') === 'password') {
        $(".pwd").attr('type', 'text');
    } else {
        $(".pwd").attr('type', 'password');
    }
});
```